# Get Audience Manager Contact in SDL DXA 1.4 .NET

Tags: dxa, web8, audience-manager

I am trying access the **Audience Manager Contacts** in my DXA .Net application.
I have followed the steps from SDL docs and able to create contacts using CME in Web 8 and also able to synchronize the contacts with the `Subscription Management` table using the Synchronize end Point micro service.

I have referenced the following two DLLs in the DXA Web site project to use the Audience Manager functions

1. `Sdl.AudienceManager.ContentDelivery.dll`
2. `Tridion.OutboundEmail.ContentDelivery.dll`

When trying to instantiate the `Sdl.AudienceManager.ContentDelivery.Profile.Contact` object. I am getting the following exception:

> Unable to determine the current Publication. Please make sure the Ambient Data Framework is running, or configure a DefaultPublicationId in the cd_audience_manager_conf.xml configuration file

I have installed the Ambient framework in the Session enabled Content Service. 
Is there any config file I need to add in the DXA solution as per Tridion 2013 SP1 or the discovery service will handle this?

Please help!

**Edit 1**

I have modified and added the `cd_Audience_Manager_Conf.xml` in the DXA.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration Version="8.1">  
    <Email>
      <OpenImage>MailOpened.gif</OpenImage>
    </Email>
    <Redirect> 
      <ErrorResolvingLink>Resolve.html</ErrorResolvingLink>   
      <ErrorResolvingBinary>Empty.gif</ErrorResolvingBinary>
      <GeneralError>Error.html</GeneralError>
      <AppendTrackingInfo>false</AppendTrackingInfo>
    </Redirect>
    <AmbientData>
       <CacheDuration>300</CacheDuration>
     </AmbientData>
     <Publications>
       <Publication Id="27">      
        </Publication>
      </Publications>
  </Configuration>
```

Apart from that I also tried to add `cd_storage_conf.xml` and the jars in the bbin\Lib folder in the DXA solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration Version="8.1">
    <Global>

        <Storages>
            <StorageBindings>
                <Bundle src="AudienceManagerDAOBundle.xml"/>
            </StorageBindings>
           <Storage Id="profiledb" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory" Type="persistence" dialect="MSSQL">
              <Pool CheckoutTimeout="120" IdleTimeout="120" MonitorInterval="60" Size="5" Type="jdbc"/>
              <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                  <Property Name="serverName" Value="WSV001704"/>
                  <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433"/>
                  <Property Name="databaseName" Value="tridion_submgmt"/>
                  <Property Name="user" Value="TMSSMUSER"/>
                  <Property Name="password" Value="Tridion!232!"/>
              </DataSource>
            </Storage>          

          <Storage Id="trackingdb" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory" Type="persistence" dialect="MSSQL">
            <Pool CheckoutTimeout="120" IdleTimeout="120" MonitorInterval="60" Size="5" Type="jdbc"/>
            <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                <Property Name="serverName" Value="WSV001704"/>
                <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433"/>
                <Property Name="databaseName" Value="tridion_tracking"/>
                <Property Name="user" Value="TMSPSUSER"/>
                <Property Name="password" Value="Tridion!232!"/>
            </DataSource>
          </Storage>
        </Storages>
    </Global>

    <!-- Audience Manager type mappings -->
    <ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultFile">
        <Item typeMapping="AudienceManagerProfile" storageId="profiledb"/>
        <Item typeMapping="AudienceManagerTracking" storageId="trackingdb"/>
    </ItemTypes>
    <License Location="c:\SDLWeb\cd_licenses.xml"/>
</Configuration>
```

still I am getting the same error. Is there any other work around?

Comment: We have an Audience Manager integration scheduled on the backlog for DXA 1.6, that should arrive around Q3 2016

Comment: Do you see an info log line before that, stating something like "Unable to get Page Metadata for Url: ..."?

Comment: @Peter: No there is not any info or Debug log before the exception related to this.

Comment: No further info means that it could not get a ClaimStore from the ADF, so it suggests that that it is not properly configured.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Audience Manager needs to know the current Publication. It can do that in one of two ways:

1. Figure it out based on the current URL.
2. Read a configuration setting that you've manually set.

When looking it up based on the URL, it first tries to extract the URL from the Ambient Data Framework (`taf:request:full_url` claim) and then looks up the page using the `GetPageMetaByURL` method of the `DynamicMetaRetriever` class.

If any of those steps fail, it will typically log the reason (i.e. unable to read the page metadata) and then fall back to option #2: reading the `DefaultPublicationId` setting from `cd_audience_manager_conf.xml`.

If not found, it has no way of knowing the current Publication and so cannot contact the right Audience Manager standalone service.

Comment: I have created a user registration form in DXA to store the contacts in subscription mgmt Table,  which is not a Tridion Page. So the chance of getting the Page meta is very less. The second point to add a `DefaultPublicationId` in the `cd_audience_manager_conf.xml`. Can you help me in which section of the config file shall I add. As it seems the config file does not contain any section to configure the publication ID. Also where I will add this config file: In the DXA solution or in the Micro services?

Comment: Add it under the root element, in the configuration file that is in your DXA solution.

Comment: I have tried this and mentioned in the question. Is the cd_Audience_Manager_conf.xml file is correctly modified as per requirement. The xml is in the question.

Comment: No, it's not correct. You've added a whole "Publications" section with sub-elements. The setting is literally called DefaultPublicationId and should only have the ID of the publication as text: `<DefaultPublicationId>27</DefaultPublicationId>`